# Align xtable columns based on dataframe column type R

Tags: r, dataframe, knitr, xtable

I am using `xtable` in `knitr` to create tables and currently I left align all `xtable` columns because it is easy and repeatable.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to align the `xtable` columns depending on the type of data in the dataframe column (num, chr, int, etc...) so that I can right align numbers and left align characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's already the case : from xtable example page

```
 precip
             Mobile              Juneau             Phoenix         Little Rock         Los Angeles          Sacramento       San Francisco 
               67.0                54.7                 7.0                48.5                14.0                17.2                20.7 
             Denver            Hartford          Wilmington          Washington        Jacksonville               Miami             Atlanta 
               13.0                43.4                40.2                38.9                54.5                59.8                48.3 
           Honolulu               Boise             Chicago              Peoria        Indianapolis          Des Moines             Wichita 
               22.9                11.5                34.4                35.1                38.7                30.8                30.6 
         Louisville         New Orleans            Portland           Baltimore              Boston             Detroit    Sault Ste. Marie 
               43.1                56.8                40.8                41.8                42.5                31.0                31.7 
             Duluth Minneapolis/St Paul             Jackson         Kansas City            St Louis         Great Falls               Omaha 
               30.2                25.9                49.2                37.0                35.9                15.0                30.2 
               Reno             Concord       Atlantic City         Albuquerque              Albany             Buffalo            New York 
                7.2                36.2                45.5                 7.8                33.4                36.1                40.2 
          Charlotte             Raleigh             Bismark          Cincinnati           Cleveland            Columbus       Oklahoma City 
               42.7                42.5                16.2                39.0                35.0                37.0                31.4 
           Portland        Philadelphia           Pittsburg          Providence            Columbia         Sioux Falls             Memphis 
               37.6                39.9                36.2                42.8                46.4                24.7                49.1 
          Nashville              Dallas             El Paso             Houston      Salt Lake City          Burlington             Norfolk 
               46.0                35.9                 7.8                48.2                15.2                32.5                44.7 
           Richmond      Seattle Tacoma             Spokane          Charleston           Milwaukee            Cheyenne            San Juan 
               42.6                38.8                17.4                40.8                29.1                14.6                59.2 
> xalign(names(precip))# a character vector
[1] "l"
> xalign(precip)# a numeric
[1] "r
```